# Taking integration of multiple variables

Tags: integration

Is it ok to say 
$\int_{A}^{B} dxdy = \int_{A}^{B} (\int_{A}^{B}dx)dy$
? if it is true then why? thanks for helps

Comment: If $A,B$ are real numbers with $A\leq B$ then $\int_A^Bdx$ is an acceptable notation for $\int\mathbf1_{(A,B]}(x)dx=[x]_B^A=B-A$. The notation $\int_A^Bdxdy$ makes no sense.

Comment: In my former comment $[x]^A_B$ must be replaced by $[x]^B_A$. Sorry.